# Storing array data in firebase, and how ID's are generated

Tags: angularjs, firebase

I have a set of objects in my firebase data that all have an array under them. When I create the initial object, I create the initial array with its first object with a line of code like this:

```
    ref.child('items').set([{firstobject: id123}])
```

this seems to set the id to zero, as the first item in the array. However when I later try to push() a new item to the array with this line of code, I get a more complex id (ZwPiVMIrzbSdvfwxkts).

```
    ref.child('items').push(someNewObject);
```

Comment: You're calling `push()` in a `Firebase` object, which is very much **not** an array. See https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/understanding-data.html#section-arrays-in-firebase

Comment: I know that underneath firebase stores the data as an object, but I found the push() method in their arrays best practices guide. It all seems to work, just a difference in the id generated.  How else would you add a record/object to an "array" in firebase? any help is appreciated, thanks

Comment: *Disclaimer: I work for Firebase, so "their" = "your" :-)* Firebase's `push()` method is not the same as an `Array.push()`. To learn more about the reasons for that, read: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/saving-data.html#section-push

Comment: Ok, thanks Frank I see what I am doing wrong. To effectively use the array, I need to use push() instead of set() initially, then I can leverage the auto generated Id's to keep a chronological ordering of my 'items'.

Comment: Yup. Sticking to Firebase's API is usually a good idea for scalability. It's a bit awkward at first to switch from array indices to the so-called push ids, but they become second nature after a while.

Comment: I'll write it up into an answer. I wasn't sure before what your problem was, but with your final comment it is clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first line of code, you're calling the `Firebase.set()` method passing it a JavaScript array that contains a single object.

In your second line of code, you're calling the `Firebase.push()` method with an object.

Given that Firebase lists/collections are not the same as JavaScript arrays, you end up with a mismatch.

Unlike JavaScript arrays, Firebase's lists are architected to scale well in highly concurrent, multi-user scenarios. I'd recommend to use them instead of arrays from the start.

```
ref.child('items').push({firstobject: id123});
ref.child('items').push(someNewObject);
```

With this snippet, all your items will be stored under so-called push ids.